# How to use cached active directory when my Windows Store App client is offline

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, offline

I am developing a Windows Store App for a business.
The client application connects to a server and may only login to the server if it has the correct credentials and belongs to the correct domain.

But when there is no connection available for the client app to connect to the server, the user must use the cached user credentials provided by Active Directory so that the user may work offline. The problem is that Windows Store Apps uses Azure Active Directory so I have to be connected to the internet.

I would like to be able to search for the user and verify credentials, almost in the following manner using the [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) classes located in the System.DirectoryServices namespace of a normal Desktop Windows application:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
directorySearcher.FindOne();
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a conflict in what you are trying to achieve:

- you use an active directory to be able to authenticate somebody against a central user repository (which is much harder to be hacked than any local user credential representation)
- you do not want to use a central active directory because it costs you internet connection

Others do following:

- anything which can be done without authentication gets allowed on clients without authentication (eg. create a draft version of something, prepare a change proposal)
- anything which is required to be done in an authenticated manner requires real authentication with real internet connection (check in drafts to become active, apply changes)

Usually that is, where such software projects become 2-10 times as complex as authentication-only or no-authentication projects. Good luck.

Comment: Our authentication is done with a wcf service to the host but since the client is used out in the field by our technicians, a connection to the internet is not always guaranteed. So in those cases authentication must be done offline in some way. I'll figure it out, and thanks for the info!

Comment: If you have full control AND trust on the clients you can make all of them read only domain controllers. However this is a bit hacky solution and may raise security issues such as: If any laptop is lost you are at risk to expose all your user data to somebody (whoever that is). Best is as described to decouple activities that require authentication from the ones that do not.